# Appropriate Ubuntu version for my hardware

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 310 with an Intel Celeron processor, 4GB RAM and 1TB HDD. Which Ubuntu version I can install?

Comment: In short: any of them.

Answer (score 1):

I feel [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) will be the best choice for your configuration.

It comes with LXDE desktop, which is very light and fast.
All apps are too very light.

I have been using Lubuntu on my old HP and I am happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

4GB of RAM and 1TB HDD is fairly good specs. Please try [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org), [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net) or [Ubuntu Budgie](http://ubuntubudgie.org). My old laptop runs Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 fairly well. Specs: 2GB RAM and Intel Core2Duo at 1.66 GHz *2. If you want an aesthetically pleasing and fast distro try Ubuntu Budgie. (It integrates with the GNOME Stack tightly so you get the feel of the original [Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) flavour without sacrificing performance). You can make a backup of your data and give each one of them a try. All are light and fast. Ubuntu Budgie and Xubuntu are good choices if you want a lightweight, aesthetically pleasing and fast experience. 
It all depends upon your choice, which one you want. Give them all a try and choose any from them. Enjoy Ubuntu!